# Python - Comparing two lists and getting incorrect results

Tags: python

The goal of the program is to compare a list of student answers to a list of correct answers and calculate how many are answered correctly. The answer key is stored as a list of strings, and the student answers are read from a text file and then converted to uppercase to match the answer key.

```
#Read student answer file
student_answers = infile.read()
#Convert student answer to all caps
student_answers = [answer.upper() for answer in student_answers]
```

My program runs without errors, but the results of comparing the two lists are incorrect. Only 3 of the answers are showing to be correct and there are 20 correct answers. Below is the relevant code I have so far, and I have also included a screenshot of the output [Program Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYk1U.png). Only questions 1,3,5,7, and 25 should be flagged as incorrect. I have double checked both lists and they contain the correct information so its not input error. Any guidance on where I could be going wrong would be appreciated.

```
for studentLine, keyLine in zip(Student, TestKey):
    keyAnswer = keyLine.split()
    studentAnswer = studentLine.split()
    #Compare student answer to test key
    if studentAnswer == keyAnswer:
        correct += 1
        percent_score += 4
        print('Good job! Question ', index + 1, 'is correct!')
        index +=1
    if studentAnswer != keyAnswer:
        incorrect += 1
        incorrect_list.append(index + 1)
        print('The correct answer to question ', index + 1, 'is ', TestKey[index])
        index +=1
```

Comment: Try printing the values compared. That will clear things up. Also, replace `if studentAnswer != keyAnswer:` by `else:`.

Comment: Ahhh perfect, I forgot to strip the whitespace. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have incorrectly splitting instead of stripping.

So you should be using:

```
keyAnswer = keyLine.strip()
studentAnswer = studentLine.strip()
```

Comment: I have changed it to strip instead of split but I'm still showing blank spaces for every other answer. I tried to do .replace('\n','') and that s still not working. Any suggestions?